# CSS Not applying to a particular element (DIV)

Tags: html, css

So this would be my html:

```
    <body>
        <section id="info">
            <div class="status">

...
```

I am trying to style the div.status through my css file attached to the html file and the line begins like this

```
body section#info > div.status { ... }
```

I am not using any css3 properties and the element is not applying ANY of them. I am able to style an inside element though, using the straight-child ">" symbol. To do it, I just copied the line before and completed the path to the element.

I'd really appreciate some thoughts, thanks!

Comment: It works as it suppose http://jsfiddle.net/s6tvvs9b/

Comment: Why don't you just use `.status {  } ` instead of `body section#info > div.status { ... }`? Surely there's no need for all of that for one simple selector

Comment: The code as shown works, as http://jsfiddle.net/x6cjz27z/ proves. So show us an actual example, otherwise we can not tell you where you messed it up.

Comment: Yes, I feel kind of stupid to post this, but I really double checked it and can't see it ok in any of my browsers.

Comment: Did you check he jsfiddle working examples provided by two different  people?

Comment: Yes, I checked, of course I trust those, but the actual thing is still not working... :(

Comment: Then in that case, the code you posted isn't at fault. Check your file paths in relation to the HTML doc

Comment: ok here you go: http://www.euphoring.co.uk/pub/clients/fitflop THANKS!

Comment: @JuliánAbal ... what's the issue then?

Comment: This is really quite unclear as to what the problem is Julian, help us out please! :)

Comment: See the element containing the phrase "United Kingdom" (div.status>h2)? That div.status needs a background, wrote on the css (paths checked) but not displaying (Not a single property is applying to that element).
But the UNITED KINGDOM element is referenced as a straight-child in the css but it is working.

Comment: I don't want to say this, but is there any reserved set of words for css or something?

Comment: @JuliánAbal please check my latest answer

Comment: I am so embarrased I just want to delete this... haha

Comment: @JuliánAbal lol it's your call, these things happen to everyone :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file, you haven't properly closed the previous line 21, which was breaking the file causing everything beyond line 21 to be ignored.

`div.map > .countries > #country`

Should be

`div.map > .countries > #country {}`

(Or whatever you intend to put in that declaration, but just try making it empty for now and seeing if that solves the issue)

Comment: Thank you too, sir. I have no idea who downvoted your answer, I don't even have rank to do it. So, thank again, and sorry to waste your time too!

Answer (score 1):

Why you not just try to use

```
.status
{...}
```

But yours is working too.

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain why the CSS declaration has been cut short in this case

Answer (score 0):

Simply using

```
div.status { ... }
```

should work fine, or

```
section#info div.status { ... }
```

because as long as there is no interference with other elements of the same class which need to be styled differently (in which case you should probably be using a separate class), you don't need to be too specific, and the extra code increases the likelihood of syntax errors to creep into your work, breaking it.  If you're still having problems, then can you please give a sample of work with a little more info in it so we can see if the problem is coming from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

## It is working just check how css is embedded into your html!

```
body section#info > div.status { color: blue; }
```

**[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6tvvs9b/2/)**

I think the problem is in embedding the css into your file!

straight write between your head element like this

```
<head>
    <style>
        body section#info > div.status { color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
```

Or if it is separate css file! make sure path is correct!

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```